# How to cut out the exact usage from a dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

Given:

- eclipse, must be eclipse
- huge project
- maven
- large artifact A, large artifact B, A depends on B

How to determine fast, with (almost) one button push, the methods that A uses from B?
Thanks

Comment: Are you building both artifact A and artifact B?

Comment: yes, I am building them both, but I would need the exact usage of B in A.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that.
You can do it on a method basis, right-clicking on the method and then "Open call hierarchy".
You can also, in the Project Explorer, right-click on a class name and then "References".